# Use third party library in hydrid angular app - ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

I am migrating from AngularJS to Angular. I am trying to import a third party module to app.module.ts, but I have an error:

> node_modules\datatables.net-dt\css\jquery.dataTables.css.shim.ngstyle.js 
>   export { styles as styles };
>   ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' during compilation.

My gulp task compiles the css to generate a `.shim.ngstyle.js` file. 
I aso have a similar error when I try to import a module from a third party to app.module.ts during the compilation of the .js files

Here is what I did. In app.js

```
var um = require('@angular/upgrade/static');
var pb = require('@angular/platform-browser');
var fact = require('../www/app.module.ngfactory');

pb.platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(fact.AppModuleNgFactory).
 then(platformRef => {
 var upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(um.UpgradeModule);
 upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));

AppModule.directive('selectorName', downgradeComponent({component: 
ComponentName}));
```

In app.module.ts

```js
import { DataTableModule } from 'angular2-datatable'

@NgModule({ imports: [ DataTableModule ]
```

Comment: Please, show us some code !

Comment: Please, edit the original question. Don't paste code into the comments.